# Make the columns sortable in the Rep Leagues

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sorting, reputation-leagues

If the columns are sortable, you can see:

- Who are the fastest movers up or down
- What is the rank of lowest or highest rep users

Comment: indeed, great suggestion, now implemented!

Comment: @Jeff: Very nice, thanks, though I had envisioned clickable column headers and ascending as well as descending sorts. In glancing at the data I am amazed that someone, for example, in a month earns a mere 49 points and jumps 21529 positions to rank #3046 with a total reputation of 2,066.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We looked at this, but the only other two sorting criterias possible are

- total reputation
- rank change

.. is that enough to justify? three total sort orders?

Comment: Those are the two columns I mean. I think it would be cool to be able to see that. It would be like the "Gainers" on the [Stock](http://www.google.com/finance) (er, I mean "Stack") Exchange.